# Sum of the values of the rows of each column read from a CSV file

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am trying to read from a CSV file which has 10 rows and 4 columns and after reading the data, I want to add all the rows of each column.For each row of each column there is a value. Suppose, if the row1 of column1 is 0, it's value would be 3 and same goes on for each row of each column.For example, if 10 rows of a column are-
1
2
3
4
5
0
1
0
0
0
then the sum should be 16. Here is the code so far-

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        String line=null;
        try{
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath));


                while((line=br.readLine())!=null){

                    String[] distance=line.split(",");
                    System.out.println(line);    
                }
                br.close();

        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Now, I want to find the sum of all those values per column. Help in solving this problem would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What are you stuck on?

Comment: On adding the values of the rows of a column

Comment: That's a requirement, not a problem. Do you know how to parse integers? Do you know how to sum integers? Do you know how to use arrays? Be more specific about what you need help with. Otherwise you're wasting everyone's time.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: You must use a CsvReader (see [here](https://github.com/uniVocity/csv-parsers-comparison)), the following is only to demonstrate a solution.

Computing the column sum in a single-pass:

```
public class CsvReader {
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS = 4;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(Paths.get("path.to.your.csv.file"));

        int[] sumPerColumn = new int[NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS];

        while (lineScanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = lineScanner.nextLine();
            String[] values = line.split(",");

            for (int col = 0; col < values.length; col++) {
                sumPerColumn[col] += Integer.parseInt(values[col]);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sumPerColumn));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ArrayList to store the lines you have read, then write a utility method that sum the desired row from this data. Like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        String line=null;

        // here we create a container for readed and splitted lines
        ArrayList<String[]> lines = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        try{
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath));


                while((line=br.readLine())!=null){

                    String[] distance=line.split(",");

                    // here we add each readed and splitted line
                    lines.add(distance);
                    System.out.println(line);    
                }
                br.close();

        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        // here we sum for a particular column.
        int columnToSum = 4;
        int sum = sumRows(lines, columnToSum );
        System.out.println("The sum of column "+ columnToSum +" is: " + sum); 
    }


    public static int sumRows(ArrayList<String[]> lines, int columnToSum)         
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (String[] line: lines) {
            sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(line[columnToSum]);
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

Comment: It's useful. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Remeber to accept/upvote answer if it helped you. Next time you ask question on stack overflow, please explain exactly what you would like to do, what you are thinking - what are the things you don't know and what have you tried. Don't be shy to ask even "naive/silly/dumb" questions, it is much batter, because we will then know what is your understanding and how to help you.Next time be more verbose, let us know what you are thinking, so we can really help you to learn something :) Cheers!

Comment: Sure, thanks! I did try to vote but it's not being recorded